# jQuery that removes excess link text from inside anchor tags - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, regex

I've given up - why is this not working? I'm trying to process my message's links, and it works, but not all the way. [Here's the **jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YYcFZ/) and what I believe to be the heart of the issue is in **Edit 2** below.

It runs through the function and does everything except for the filter loop thing.... If you look at your console you can see it remove executes the regex on each of the `<a></a>` tags' inner text, but for some reason it doesn't keep the change all the way through! What am I doing wrong?

JavaScript (using jQuery):

```
function processTweetLinks(messagetext) {
    console.log(messagetext);
    messagetext = messagetext.replace();
    var replacePattern1, replacePattern2;
    //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
    replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
    messagetext = messagetext.replace(replacePattern1, '<a class="individualMessageBioWhateverLink" href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
    console.log('replacePattern1: ' + messagetext);

    //URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
    replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
    messagetext = messagetext.replace(replacePattern2, '$1<a class="individualMessageBioWhateverLink" href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');
    console.log('replacePatter2: ' + messagetext);
    // Ignore this block of code, it's just for future visitors that want to link #hashtags and @usernames - it works perfectly!
    /*
         exp = /(^|\s)#(\w+)/g;
       text = text.replace(exp, "$1<a class='individualMessageBioWhateverHash' href='http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23$2' target='_blank'>#$2</a>");
       console.log(text);

        exp = /(^|\s)@(\w+)/g;
        text = text.replace(exp, "$1<a class='individualMessageBioWhateverMention' href='http://www.twitter.com/$2' target='_blank'>@$2</a>");

        */
    console.log('before the a filter loop: ' + messagetext);
    $(messagetext).filter('a').each(function (e) {
        console.log(this.text);
        var finalexp = /(([a-zA-Z]{3,5}\:\/\/)|(www\.))/gim;
        var something = $(this).text().replace(finalexp, "");
        $(this).text(something);
        console.log(this.text);
        console.log(something);

        /*console.log('after each: ' + this);

         //cleans up stuff like http://www. and https://www. and ftp://www. (obviously not a value URI... - may want to stick to just https?:\/\/ for that reason)
         // /(([a-zA-Z]{3,5}\:\/\/)(www\.))/gim;

         //Cleans up all instances of www. 
         // /(www\.)/gim;
        });
        */
        //console.log(text);
    });
    $("#correctedmessagetext").html(messagetext);
    return messagetext;   
}

var individualMessage = "http://google.com is great, but http://www.stackoverflow.com may be my only hope. www.yahoo.com is out of the question.";
processTweetLinks(individualMessage);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="correctedmessagetext"></div>
```

**Edit:** I'm not actually outputting this to a div - part of another function generates a string and inside that string is a call to this function that is essentially `processTweetLinks(individualMessage)`.

**Edit 2:** This is the short version of the code - the problem must be somewhere in here:

```
$(messagetext).filter('a').each(function(e) {
        var finalexp = /(([a-zA-Z]{3,5}\:\/\/)|(www\.))/gim;
        var something = $(this).text().replace(finalexp, "");    
        $(this).text(something);
    });
    return messagetext;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're never editing them on the page.  As far as I know, you can either break up the messagetext string (put it into different vars, and then piece it back together after updating those), or you can output it to the page, and then do your filter on correctedmessagetext.  So leave this:

```
$("#correctedmessagetext").html(messagetext);
```

And then change your filter method to be another method that works on the id of correctedmessagetext, like this:

```
function doFilter() {
     $("#correctedmessagetext").filter('a').each(function (e) {
        console.log(this.text);
        var finalexp = /(([a-zA-Z]{3,5}\:\/\/)|(www\.))/gim;
        var something = $(this).text().replace(finalexp, "");
        $(this).text(something);
        console.log(this.text);
        console.log(something);

        /*console.log('after each: ' + this);

         //cleans up stuff like http://www. and https://www. and ftp://www. (obviously not a value URI... - may want to stick to just https?:\/\/ for that reason)
         // /(([a-zA-Z]{3,5}\:\/\/)(www\.))/gim;

         //Cleans up all instances of www. 
         // /(www\.)/gim;
        });
        */
        //console.log(text);
    });
}
```

After outputting the messagetext to the page (the one-liner above), then call your new method.

**EDIT**

Looking over this, you already had the answer from what you were doing before - regex replacement.  I just went over it and came up w/this method:

```
function messageFilter(messagetext) {
    var replacePattern = /(>)(([a-zA-Z]{3,5}\:\/\/)|(www\.))(www.)?(\w+\.\w+)(<)/g;

    messagetext = messagetext.replace(replacePattern, '$1$6$7');

    console.log(messagetext);
    return messagetext;
}
```

You can see it working on my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggRSR/)

This way you don't have do do a $(item).filter('a').each(function(e) anymore, and you can just call the method to fix your string.

Comment: I'll try to find another solution, but I'm thinking along these lines... While you're going through, you'll need to split up your messagetext and then do your reformatting on it, and put it back together.

Comment: That is amazing. I was pushed toward DOM manipulation yesterday when I posted a closely related question but frankly the worst possible theoretical result (as far as I can imagine) is a message with a link that isn't recognized, a link that extends all the way through to the end of the message, or a message that's missing some of its original content. No big deal. Thank you for helping me, this has been hanging up my development for the last couple days!